# 18.04 clean install very slow

Tags: performance, swap

I just upgraded an old Windows 7 laptop to dual boot with 18.04 Bionic Beaver.  Initially, bootup was very slow indeed, but I've managed to fix that - it was something to do with the Intel GM965 video driver and I had to tweak the grub file.

However, after login, startup is very slow, all apps run very slow, keyboard buffer is painful, everything is paralyzingly slow. The Windows installation runs about 8 times quicker, so it's not just me being impatient. It has 300Gb of disk space and 2Gb of RAM.

I ran systemd-analyze critical-chain and it came up with a lot of red lines:

```
john@D630:~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 40.199s
└─multi-user.target @1min 40.198s
  └─kerneloops.service @42.124s +392ms
    └─network-online.target @42.058s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @35.276s +6.760s
        └─NetworkManager.service @22.986s +12.231s
          └─dbus.service @20.262s
            └─basic.target @20.208s
              └─sockets.target @20.204s
                └─snapd.socket @20.077s +90ms
                  └─sysinit.target @19.723s
                    └─systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service @40.317
                      └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @19.252s
                        └─system.slice @3.642s
                          └─-.slice @3.598s
lines 1-18/18 (END)
```

Sorry - I don't know how to format it correctly.

The PC is behaving like it doesn't have a swap file, and some other posts seem to indicate that this may be the problem, but I can't work out how to display my current swap file details.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks,

JM

Comment: OK, I ran swapon  -s,  and got size 2097148,  used 524,  which seems (to me) very low.   How can I tell if the swap file is actually being used?

Comment: It is unclear what has been upgraded on the "old laptop". I'd say it is a miracle anything works without a CPU. Hard to believe, but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I have doubts that swap is really your problem. Check first if you have any processes that are consuming a lot of CPU; use the "top" command.

"top" will also show free and used RAM and swap. Or you could use "free -m" for that.

Comment: Just ran Software Update (although I had ticked it during the install) and I was still watching the terminal scroll 3 hours later... 

After restart, boot time now OK, startup after login acceptable. Programs now load in a reasonable time. However, ran Firefox, and it still seems very slow indeed. Ran "top" and it's telling me that FF is using 54% of CPU with only 1 tab open (gmail inbox), and 20% for Web content. Seems very high.  Do you have any other recommendations for diagnosing performance issues?  Using a hard network connection, and the upload/download speeds are similar to this PC.

Comment: Firefox using 54% CPU constantly is not normal. When you do something in the browser, yes, it can peak; it can even use 100% of several CPU cores; but only for a short while. After a page is fully loaded, it should come back down to a low one-digit percent number. Does that only happen on that one web page, or on others as well? You could try to temporarily disable any Firefox extensions that you have. If that helps, re-enable them one by one and watch CPU usage.

Comment: Happens on all web pages that I have tried (gmail,  BBC Sounds, which is unlistenable,  Mozilla support,  Askubuntu). If I go to "about:config", it drops to sub 10%.  My Firefox has no extensions enabled,  and only the bare minimum of plugins.  But something about the slow screen response makes me wonder if it's driver related.  Right now I've opened a second tab (to BBC 6 - but not streaming - it's on pause), and CPU% is a steady 65+ for FF, 50+ for Web content.  I'm still wondering about those Network-Manager lines in sytemd-analyze

Comment: And the Intel GM965 graphics device;  things don't seem to get noticeably slow until I want to interact with an application.  Like maybe a mouse-click.  If I'm in Terminal,  a mouse click to switch to FF takes a long few seconds to take effect.

Comment: Hm... of course it's always possible that there is a problem with that graphics driver. But you might indeed be very low on RAM with only 2 GB: If switching from one graphical application to another (terminal window -> Firefox) takes a long time, that might point to that general direction. It is entirely possible that the system needs to swap Firefox back in, and that might take a while. Did you monitor your RAM / swap usage? ("free -m" or even in the top lines of the "top" command).

Comment: You could try a live system running from a USB stick for comparison, preferably with a lighter-weight desktop; Xubuntu 20.04 comes to mind. And maybe also try a different browser like Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

I tried free -m and it looks like this:

```
       Total     Used    Free
Mem     1983     1366      81
Swap    2047      388    1659
```

Maybe I do need more RAM, but Windows 7 (this is a dual boot machine) is still quicker (not quick;  just not as slow). I'm thinking of trying Linux Mint 18, which goes like a train on my little ASUS eee,  which was very slow when it used Windows.

Many thanks for all the helpful advice,  BTW.

Comment: Acutally, that "free" output doesn't look too bad. The Linux kernel always tends to swap out some stuff that isn't in active use, thus 388 MB used swap doesn't mean that the kernel is desperate for RAM; it is only reserving RAM in case some is needed urgently.

Comment: You could till try to install the Xfce desktop and try using that for comparison; it's less resource-hungry than GNOME 3 which is the default for Ubuntu. You can install another desktop on top of the existing system and choose the one to use for each session from the graphical login.

Comment: Thank you - I'll look into the Xfce option;  it sounds less drastic than a complete reinstall.